# Destructuring to get the last element of an array in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

In [CoffeeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), this is straightforward:

```
coffee> a = ['a', 'b', 'program']
[ 'a', 'b', 'program' ]
coffee> [_..., b] = a
[ 'a', 'b', 'program' ]
coffee> b
'program'
```

Does [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) allow for something similar?

```
> const [, b] = [1, 2, 3]
'use strict'
> b  // it got the second element, not the last one!
2
> const [...butLast, last] = [1, 2, 3]
SyntaxError: repl: Unexpected token (1:17)
> 1 | const [...butLast, last] = [1, 2, 3]
    |                  ^
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:24:13)
```

Of course I can do it the [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009) way -

```
const a = b[b.length - 1]
```

But maybe this is a bit prone to off-by-one errors. Can the splat only be the last thing in the destructuring?

Comment: @FelixKling the question is in particular about the behavior of `...` in es6, particularly that it can only be used as the last thing when destructuring or in a parameter list. This is potentially counterintuitive to someone coming into es6 from coffeescript and thus this question is potentially useful.

Comment: That means besides `[1,2,3].slice(-1)` you even can't destructure equivalent to `[1,2,3].slice(0, -1)`. These are common operations. ES6 destructuring is somehow a joke!

Comment: @Iven there is a legitimate reason - to handle infinite iterables.

Comment: Too bad rest as first parameter doesn't work. Would have been cool... Here is a jsperf using some of the answers https://jsperf.com/destructure-last/1

Comment: There’s a [TC39 proposal called _Double-Ended Iterator and Destructuring_](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-deiter) that links to this question.

Comment: what's wrong with `const [c] = ['bee'].slice(-1)`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is not possible in ES6/2015. The standard just doesn't provide for it.

As you can see in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions), the `FormalParameterList` can either be:

- a `FunctionRestParameter`
- a `FormalsList` (a list of parametes)
- a `FormalsList`, followed by a `FunctionRestParameter`

Having `FunctionRestParameter` followed by parameters is not provided.

Answer (score 265):

```js
console.log('last', [1, 3, 4, 5].slice(-1));
console.log('second_to_last', [1, 3, 4, 5].slice(-2));
```

Comment: Nice simple non-mutative solution.

Comment: @Shanimal Depends, I'm getting the `pop` version as faster (OS X, Chrome 68).

Comment: @Dave Newton But pop() cause mutation

Comment: @AntonioPantano Yes, it mutates the copy. Point was whether or not it's faster isn't a given.

Comment: should be the selected solution

Comment: to return the value `'program'` and not `['program']` use `['a','b','program'].slice(-1)[0]`. for empty array this will return `undefined`

Comment: from es2022 onward you can do `['a','b','program'].at(-1)` instead

Answer (score 75):

I believe ES6 could at least help with that:

```
[...arr].pop()
```

Given your array (arr) is not undefined and an iterable element (yes, even strings work!!), it should return the last element..even for the empty array and it doesn't alter it either. It creates an intermediate array though..but that should not cost much.

Your example would then look like this:

```js
  console.log(  [...['a', 'b', 'program']].pop() );
```

Comment: uhh, it's quite bad, even `.slice(-1)[0]` is slighly less bad, or `var [last]=arr.slice().reverse()` is another ugly one if you need

Comment: I thought this post was about ES6/ES2015, no?

But I like especially your last piece. How about combining the two: ```var [last] = arr.slice(-1)``` ;)

Comment: my favorite way is `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, -1, { get() {return this[this.length - 1] } }); [1,2,3][-1]`

Comment: I love javascript :)

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; eval(\`[${('' + a).replace(/[^,]/g, '')}x] = a\`); x` yields `5` :)

Comment: @shaunc: This only works for simple types, try adding an object to the array.

Comment: Although this works it's mutative and removes the item from the original array. Not ideal in many scenarios.

Comment: @GavKilbride it doesn't. Example is the same as `[].concat(arr).pop();` which doesn't mutate `arr`.

Comment: @caub for your first comment, instead of the reverse, I'd probably do `let [last] = arr.slice(-1);` instead of reverse if you're going to use slice and destructuring anyway

Comment: @Hashbrown yea, also note that JS has `arr.at(-1)` now

Answer (score 62):

You can destructure the reversed array to get close to what you want.

```js
const [a, ...rest] = ['a', 'b', 'program'].reverse();
  
document.body.innerHTML = 
    "<pre>"
    + "a: " + JSON.stringify(a) + "\n\n"
    + "rest: " + JSON.stringify(rest.reverse())
    + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Smart. Better than `const last = ['bbb', 'uuu', 'iii'].slice(-1);` ? In terms of performances?

Comment: the `.slice(-1)` is technically faster, but it does not give you both the last item AND the subarray in one call, which is a benefit of the `...` splat when destructuring. Performance hit of reversing twice is to be considered when used on longer arrays, but for a small script probably worth the convenience? But you could just as easily `let a = array.slice(-1), rest = array.slice(0,array.length-2)` if you still wanted the oneliner in ES5, that is ~4% faster. https://jsperf.com/last-array-splat

Comment: this is quite clever :D

Comment: This solution still mutates the original array , which is not ideal in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 47):

Another approach is:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const { length, [length - 1]: last } = arr; // Should be 5
console.log(last)
```

Comment: You don’t have to catch the `length`. `...rest` would be more useful.

Comment: @КонстантинВан true, it's common, mine is rare, but trully useful

Comment: This is a gem @DenKerny !

Answer (score 10):

You can try using object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) applied to an array to extract the `length` and then get last item: e.g.:

```js
const { length, 0: first, [length - 1]: last } = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

// length = 4
// first = 'a'
// last = 'd'
```

### UPDATE

Another approach [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

> The at() method takes an integer value and returns the item at that index, allowing for positive and negative integers...

```js
const last = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].at(-1)
// 'd'
```

Comment: I really think this is the best way to do it for now (mid 2022)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: at() is more convenient because it returns the element, whereas slice() returns an array.

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessarily the most performant way of doing it. But depending on the context, a quite elegant way would be:

```js
const myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const theOneIWant = [...myArray].pop();

console.log(theOneIWant); // 'three'
console.log(myArray.length); // 3
```

Comment: I don't see any elegance in this solution, but anyway @shoesel already posted it

Comment: how personal taste differs ;) I like it

Comment: In what way is it elegant?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*

Answer (score 8):

Getting the last element of the array:

```
const [last,] = ['a', 'b', 'program'].reverse();
```

Comment: I must add that JavaScript Array reverse is done in-place. So this solution might not suit every person, and/or have performance issues. I've been burned...

Comment: Basically the same as [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676072). It still has the same problem of mutating the array.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
const [lastone] = myArray.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

const {
  [arr.length - 1]: last
} = arr;

console.log(last); // => 'c'
```

Comment: Yes, I find it useful when already doing other destructuring. By itself it is not as easy to read as the classic solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the destructuring way, but it could help. According to JavaScript documentation and the [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reverse) method, one could be trying this:

```
const reversed = array1.reverse();
let last_item = reversed[0]
```

Comment: There is no advantage at all to use `reverse()`. It takes unnecessary time and it mutates the array which is most likely also unnecessary. With mutation `.pop()` should be the idiomatic way to get the last item. Without mutation it's `arr[arr.length - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

You could further destruct array´s `...rest` array as `Object`, in order to get its `length` prop and build a [computed prop name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) for the last index.

This even works for parameter destruction:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Destruct from array ---------------------------
const [A_first, ...{length: l, [l - 1]: A_Last}] = a;
console.log('A: first: %o; last: %o', A_first, A_Last);     // A: first: 1; last: 4

// Destruct from fn param(s) ---------------------
const fn = ([B_first, ...{length: l, [l - 1]: B_Last}]) => {
  console.log('B: first: %o; last: %o', B_first, B_Last);   // B: first: 1; last: 4
};

fn(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does ES6 allow for something similar?

**No, it is currently not possible,** although we may get it in the future, see:

- [Double-Ended Iterator and Destructuring](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-deiter)

So what *can* we do in the meantime?

We want:

```js
const [...rest, last] = arr;
```

For the time being, probably the cleanest approach is:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const [rest, last] = [arr.slice(0, -1), arr.at(-1)];

console.log({ rest, last });
```

which logs: `{ rest: [ 1, 2 ], last: 3 }` and `arr` is unchanged. It does not create unnecessary copies or intermediate arrays.

Note that `.at()` is fairly new (as of writing):

- [Can I use `Array at`?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_at)

Another approach that does not use `arr.at(-1)`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const rest = [...arr];
const last = rest.pop(); // <-- this mutates rest

console.log({ rest, last });
```

which logs: `{ rest: [ 1, 2 ], last: 3 }` and `arr` is unchanged since we made a shallow copy first. It does not create unnecessary copies of `arr` or intermediate arrays either. However, I do not like the fact that `rest` is mutated.

If backward compatibility is important, this works even in [ES3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var rest = arr.slice();
var last = rest.pop(); // <-- this mutates rest

console.log({ rest: rest, last: last });
```

It is not as elegant as `const [...rest, last] = arr;`, but the code is readable and straightforward in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr[arr.length - 1] = 6;

// => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple and understandable one I could actually come up with:

```
    const first = [...arr];
    const last = first.pop();
    const others = first.join(', ');
```

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, the question is about [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for JavaScript arrays, and we know it is not possible to have the last item of an array by using the destructuring assignment, but there is a way to do it **immutable**. See the following:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'last'];

~~~
const arrLength = arr.length - 1;

const allExceptTheLast = arr.filter( (_, index) => index !== arrLength );
const [ theLastItem ] = arr.filter( (_, index) => index === arrLength );
```

We do not mutate the `arr` variable, but we still have all the array members, except the last item as an array and have the last item separately.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let [b] = [...a].reverse()
```

Answer (score -1):

Using array deconstructing: "capturing" the `array`, "`splice`d" array (`arrMinusEnd`), and "`pop`ed"/"`slice`d" element (`endItem`).

```js
var [array, arrMinusEnd, endItem] = 
  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
  .reduce(
    (acc, cv, idx, arr) => {
      if(idx<arr.length-1) acc[1].push(cv);
      else {
        acc[0]=arr;
        acc[2]=cv;
      };
      return acc;
    },
    [null,[],[]]
  )
;

console.log("array=");
console.log(array);
console.log("arrMinusEnd=");
console.log(arrMinusEnd);
console.log("endItem=\""+endItem+"\"");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple one,

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const last = arr.at(-1);
console.log(last);
```