# Get first and last elements in array, ES6 way

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

`let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`

Documentation is something like this

`[first, ...rest] = array` will output 1 and the rest of array

Now is there a way to take only the first and the last element `1 & 0` with `Destructuring`

ex: `[first, ...middle, last] = array`

I know how to take the first and last elements the other way but I was wondering if it is possible with es6

Comment: There can be no parameters after rest parameter.

Comment: `let {0: first, [array.length-1]: last} = array;` :-D

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064377/destructuring-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-es6

Comment: @Bergi well, yeah that is a clean way.

Comment: **First:** `[first] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].slice(0, 1)`. **Last:** `[last] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].slice(-1)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) can only use at the end not anywhere else in the destructuring so it won't work as you expected.

Instead, you can [destructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) certain properties(an array is also an object in JS), for example, `0` for first and index of the last element for last.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

let {0 : a ,[array.length - 1] : b} = array;
console.log(a, b)
```

---

Or its better way to extract length as an another variable and get last value based on that ( suggested by @Bergi) , it would work even there is no variable which refers the array.

```js
let {0 : a ,length : l, [l - 1] : b} = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: It's a rest not a spread FYI, and it's not an operator, it's just syntax.

Comment: Uh, yeah, but don't do that. `let a = array[0], b = array[array.length-1];`  is just so much cleaner. If we really wanted to make it as concise as possible, there's also `let {0:a, length:l, [l-1]:b} = array;`

Comment: @bergi is `l` get defined just before assigning value into b???

Comment: Yes, it's evaluated strictly left-to-right

Comment: @bergi thanks, now it's clear to me :)

Comment: `const { 0: first, [array.length - 1]: last, ...middle } = array;`
________________________________________________________________________
`console.log(first, Object.values(middle), last);`