# JavaScript Destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was looking for info on JavaScript destructuring and found the video "Destructuring Assignment" as part of a video series from Packt Publication. At the very beginning of the video, I saw the following code:

```
var [a, b] = [1,2,3];
a === 1;
b === 3;
```

The presenter then explains why variable b is 3 and not 2, which didn't seem correct to me, but I thought maybe I'm wrong.

So I did a Code Pen with the following code:

```
var [a, b] = [1,2,3]
console.log(a,b) //1 2
```

As I expected, the variable b is 2.

Is there something I'm missing and not understanding?

Below is a screenshot of the video in questions.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the video appears to just be wrong.

Comment: Post a link to the video

Comment: Here's a link to the video
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-ecmascript-6/9781785882685/video4_2.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the video is wrong, these below are the only ways to get the 3 in this array (using two variables names):

```
const [a, , b] = [1, 2, 3]; // b is 3
const [a, ...b] = [1, 2, 3]; // b is [2, 3], so b[1] is 3
```

Also, see: [Destructuring to get the last element of an array in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064377/destructuring-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-es6)

Comment: Thanks for showing the different ways to get the value of 3.