# Splitting a string that has been already split

Tags: javascript, split, jspdf

I am working with jsPDF and have a variable joke and use .[splitTextToSize](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-split_text_to_size.html#%7EsplitTextToSize) to have it display nicely on the page.

```
var doc = new jsPDF()

var joke = "A Computer Science student at MIT showed up at his buddies dorm room with a new bike. His buddy said sweet bike, where’d ya get it? You’ll never believe this, he said, I was walking across campus and this beautiful blonde on a bike stopped, threw down her bike, tore off all her clothes and said _take whatever you want!_ His buddy stared at him blankly for a minute, then said smart. Her clothes would have never fit you.";

var line = doc.splitTextToSize(joke, 100)

doc.text(10,10, line)
```

The document now contains the following.

```
A Computer Science student at MIT 
showed up at his buddies dorm room  
with a new bike. His buddy said sweet 
bike, where’d ya get it? You’ll never 
believe this, he said, I was walking 
across campus and this beautiful 
blonde on a bike stopped, threw down 
her bike, tore off all her clothes and 
said _take whatever you want!_ 
His buddy stared at him blankly for a 
minute, then said smart. Her clothes 
would have never fit you.
```

Is there way to get the split `var line` and retrieve the last three line of the string? I was wondering if you can split by line number

```
His buddy stared at him blankly for a
minute, then said smart. Her clothes 
would have never fit you.
```

Comment: `.split('\n').slice(-3).join('\n')` should do it

Answer (score 0):

since it returns an array you can just :

```js
var line = doc.splitTextToSize(joke, 100).slice(-3)
```

some reading you might find helpful: [Destructuring to get the last element of an array in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064377/destructuring-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-es6)